# Are there any real benefits to including javascript dynamically rather than as script tags at the bottom of an html page

Tags: jquery-plugins

I've read that including the scripts dynamically may provide some better performance, however i'm not really seeing that on the small local tests I'm doing.  I created a jquery plugin to dynamically load other plugins as necessary and am curious as to if this is actually a good idea.   The following would be called onready or at the bottom of the page(I can provide the source for the plugin if anyone is interested):

```
  $.fn.executePlugin(
    'qtip',  // looks in default folder
    {
    required: '/javascript/plugin/easing.js',  // not really required for qtip just testing it
    version: 1,  //used for versioning and caching
    checkelement: '#thumbnail',  // will not include plugin if $(element).length==0
    css: 'page.css',  // include this css file as well with plugin
    cache:true,   // $.ajax will use cache:true
    success:function()  {  // success function to be called after the plugin loads - apply qtip to an element
        $('#thumbnail').qtip(
        {
        content: 'Some basic content for the tooltip', // Give it some content, in this case a simple string
        style: {name:'cream'},
        });                   

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think loading Javascript *on demand* is a good idea because it reduces bandwidth and page load times. A [Microsoft Research Project (Doloto)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/doloto/) takes this concept even further: They generate empty `function` stubs and lazily fetch code when it is invoked.

However, on many sites you already know *at compile time* which Javascript the page requires and can leverage the numerous optimization methods (combination, compression, minification, etc.) *in a build step* to produce the one ideal Javascript request at the bottom of the page.

I've found that a combination of the above often works well, loading *essential* Javascript in one compiled request at the bottom of the page and javascript required by features on demand.